# Optimization using Hungarian Algorithm

Tags: optimization

I have a problem where I have to pair workers to perform task. This means that each pair p-q can only perform a task t. I have to optimally find for each task t, which pair can best perform the task optimally for assignment.

How can I convert this problem to a matrix that I can solve using the Hungarian algorithm because obviously this cannot be a nxn matrix that is easily solved by the algorithm. Or is there an algorithm that I can use for such a case?

Comment: Is there some kind of weighting here that you haven't mentioned?  The Hungarian algorithm is for *weighted* bipartite matching.  If I understand your description, the problem you have is neither bipartite nor weighted, so I wonder why you think the Hungarian algorithm would be applicable.  When I say it isn't bipartite, I mean I don't see why worker $p$ couldn't be paired with $q$ to do task $t$ or paired with $r$ to do task $s$.

Comment: Hi, this is for a weighted bipartite graph, where the weight _w_ of each edge is the cost that each group of two workers  _p-q_  can do for task _t_.

So I need  to find an optimal assingment for each group of users to each task.

Comment: So no worker belongs to more than one group?  If this is so, I don't see the problem.  The Hungarian does not require that the number of tasks and the number of (pairs of) workers be the same.

Comment: If I have (_p-q_) pairs on the left side say, Set A, and then I only have _t_ tasks on the right side say Set B. 

How do I apply the Hungarian Algorithm such that I find optimal matching of pairs to tasks. Remember:

................_p1_ can either be matched with (_q1_,_q2_ . . .) for task _t1_ also.....................
_p2_ can either be matched with (_q1_,_q2_ . . .) for task _t1_
..............._p3_ can either be matched with (_q1_,_q2_ . . .) for task _t1_

BUUUT If _p1__q2_ matching is optimal for _t1_, then p1__q1 is no longer relevant.

Comment: This is not really a bipartite graph.  It's a weighted $3-$uniform [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph).  The Hungarian algorithm doesn't apply directly.  What leads you to believe that it can be made to work?

Comment: Wait a bit.  Is there something different about the p's and q's?  Is it something like each task requires a designer and a developer and no one is both a designer and a developer?

Comment: Alright,I'm currently looking at hypergraphs to see if they can work here. Yes, absolutely. Its like each task _t_ needs both designer _d_  from set A and developer _p_ from Set B but these are all from a set of users. But I need to choose the designer-developer pair wise and optimally for each task on the right. I also tried looking into Hopcroft-Karp Algorithm, i am not sure if it can perform the optimum assingment.

Comment: Apparently, even the unweighted problem is NP-hard.  I've done some Googling, and found out that the (unweighted) problem is called [three-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching).

Comment: Alright thank you. Are there existing algorithms that solve these types of bipartite graphs you know? I will look to see if there are some that exist.

Comment: No, I don't know any way to solve problems like this.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: Thanks you for introducing me to this problem.  I've always liked matching.